# Two comboboxes with the same CollectionViewSource ItemSource update each other

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, collectionviewsource

On my ViewModel, I have 2 properties (both implement property changed notifications) :

```
CountryOfIssue
Nationality
```

On my View, I have a CollectionViewSource pointing to a local instance of my Entity Framework context :

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCountries" Source="{Binding LocalContext.Countries}" CollectionViewType="{x:Type ListCollectionView}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Also on this page, I have two comboboxes used to set the values of CountryOfIssue and Nationality :

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditCountryOfIssue}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCountries}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedItem="{Binding CountryOfIssue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditNationality}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCountries}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedItem="{Binding Nationality, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

With this setup, whenever I change one of the comboboxes' value, the other one changes as well... Is this expected behavior?

(I've implemented a fix by using another CollectionViewSource, I just want to know if this is normal)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is normal, `CollectionViews` have a `CurrentItem` and if the `ItemsSource` is a `CollectionView` they get synchronized, see [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx):

> **true** if the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is always synchronized with the current item in the [ItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx); **false** if the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is never synchronized with the current item; **null** if the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) is synchronized with the current item only if the [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) uses a [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx). The default value is **null**.

So you can just turn it off manually by setting that property to `false`.

(By the way, you can also bind to the `CurrentItem` of a `CollectionView` via a slash. e.g. `People/Name` binds to the `Name` property of the current person in `People`.)

Comment: This helped me when I had multiple `ComboBox` elements in a `DataGrid` column's cells, and a new instance of `CollectionViewSource` was causing them to all set to the same value when changed.